# simple select query arguments passing issue

Tags: android

I am new with android.

I just wanted to take the count of number of rows in table against particular user in DB (uid is column in db).

For this purpose i made following function:

```
 public int getCount(int uid)
    {
        String query = "select count(*) from "+TABLE_MESSAGES+ " WHERE uid=?";

        Cursor c = ourDB.rawQuery(query,uid);

    }
```

But its giving me error:

> The method rawQuery(String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is
>   not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

also want to know how can i be able to return count from this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use this WAY:

```
public int getCount(int uid)
{
    String query = "select count(*) from "+TABLE_MESSAGES+ " WHERE uid="+uid+"";

    Cursor c = ourDB.rawQuery(query,null);

    if(c.getCount()>0)
    c.moveToFirst();

    do{

    int id = c.getInt(0);

    }while(c.moveToNext());

}
```

Comment: if you are passing `uid` directly in query itself why you require `?`, THATS WRONG....

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way**

```
public int getCount(int uid){
        try{
            String query = "select count(*)'count' from "+TABLE_MESSAGES+ " WHERE uid="+uid+"";

            Cursor c = ourDB.rawQuery(query,null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                return Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

            }
        }catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change your query to:

```
String query = "select count(*) from "+TABLE_MESSAGES+ " WHERE uid="+uid;

Cursor c = ourDB.rawQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The method rawQuery(String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is
>   not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Clearly states you are passing int instead of expected String[]

```
Cursor c = ourDB.rawQuery(query,new String[]{ uid });
```

Answer (score 1):

use the query as :

```
"SELECT * FROM <DB_NAME> WHERE uid="+uid
```

and then use the getCount() method on the cursor
like :

```
Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("above query string here");
int count = csr.getCount();
```